# foreign character displaying strangley

Tags: php, mysql

I have this character in my database:

```
É
```

But it comes out as

```
G
```

I've tried entering in the html char code into the database but this results in a null output on the site.

My database (MYSQL) is set to UTF8. All other foreign characters come out fine.

Im using PHP and apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention UTF8 in your sql query too. It will resolve the issue.

Updated:

```
<?php 
$link2 = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1',TRUE); 
mysql_selectdb('db2',$link2); 
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link2); 

?>
```

Comment: here you go: `mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); $res = mysql_query("SELECT foo FROM bar");` [see manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-connection.html)